# iOS 9, Swift 3: UIPopoverPresentationController dismisses itself on rotation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift3

My popup controller dismisses himself and re-apeares on iPad rotation. I present the popup on `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view` because it is called from sidemenu of application. Please see my code:

```
func popoverController(controller: UIViewController) {

    let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller)
    UIUtils.setMainNavigationBar(nav: (nc.navigationBar))
    nc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
    let popover = nc.popoverPresentationController!
    controller.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 548, height: 532)
    popover.delegate = self
    popover.permittedArrowDirections = .init(rawValue: 0)
    let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!
    let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view
    popover.sourceView = root
    popover.sourceRect = CGRect(x: window.bounds.width / 2, y: window.bounds.height / 2, width: 0, height: 0)

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(nc, animated: true, completion: {

        let _ = Utils.returnSideMenuRootVC()
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(self.overlay.darkOverlay())
    })
}

func prepareForPopoverPresentation(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {


}

func popoverPresentationController(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverTo rect: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGRect>, in view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<UIView>) {

    let x = popoverPresentationController.presentingViewController.view.center
    let newRect = CGRect(x: x.x, y: x.y, width: 0, height: 0)
    rect.initialize(to: newRect)
}

func popoverPresentationControllerShouldDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) -> Bool {

    removeBackground()
    return true
}

func popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover(_ popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController) {

}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: if you haven't any particular specification you can present the popover directly from the current view controller, I don't think it is necessary to display from the root view controller taken from the window.

Comment: Tried already. Doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Check here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1694/_index.html